# How to open a frame in the same page c# with a global MenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I am trying to create an small application. I want to use MenuStrip as a global menu "menu over all the subforms." However, when I click on an item of the MenuStrip I want to open up a different form "page" in the same main form. I am currently using windows Forms.

Here is what I am doing

```
private void addInventoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var addInventory = new addInventory();
    addInventory.Show();
}

private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

When I click on addInventoryToolStripMenuItem the addInventory form open up "as a pop up." What I want is to open the form in the same window "so the new form will have the same global MenuStrip on the top." What I would like to do is to keep the top menu on all forms but then when a user clicks on a menu item, the new form should load in the same page. so the user can only use one form and they have click on a different menu item to load a different form. So there have to be one form viable at all time. no blank screen.

**EDITED:** As I was googling I found a way to inherit the menu. So I created a base form and then on the other forms I inherited the base form. so Now I can see the same menu on all the forms. But the problem is when I click on a menu item a second form open. I just want it to open in the same window. how can this be done?

Please Help

Comment: Sounds like an [MDI Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Using MDI a user can have multiple windows open or have no form open. I need to have only 1 form open. so when a user clicks on an item of the menu the other form is loaded in the same place .

Comment: Maybe your aiming at customcontrol that will dynamically be placed on the form surface acting like if it was a whole new interface...but also consider the tabcontrol,if you know the control you get the point :)

Comment: You may want to check out my answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236668/multiple-forms-one-windows-c-sharp-possible-or-only-panels-usercontrol/24238483#24238483)